# How can I get videos on carousel to stop when I move to the next slide

Tags: reactjs, carousel

Title: Video not stopping when moving to next slide using Bootstrap React

Description: I'm building a video carousel using the Bootstrap React library and ReactPlayer. The videos play fine, but when I move to the next slide, the video from the previous slide continues playing. I'm looking for a way to stop the video when the user moves to the next slide.

```
import "./VideoCarousel.css";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
import Vid1 from "../videos/vid1.mp4";
import Vid2 from "../videos/vid2.mp4";
import Vid3 from "../videos/vid3.mp4";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";



const VideoCarousel = () => {
  

  const videoProperties = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Video 1",
      src: Vid1,
      credit: "Video by Ignis Productions",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Video 2",
      src: Vid2,
      credit: "Video by Ignis Productions",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Video 3",
      src: Vid3,
      credit: "Video by Ignis Productions",
    },
  ];


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel >
        {videoProperties.map((videoObj) => {
          return (
            <Carousel.Item key={videoObj.id}>
              <ReactPlayer
                url={videoObj.src}
                pip={true}
                controls={true}
                playing={false}
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>{videoObj.title}</h3>
                <p>{videoObj.credit}</p>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `<ReactPlayer />` component, you can add a `useEffect` that runs anytime the `url` prop changes, and stops all videos from playing.

```
useEffect(() => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video')).forEach(video => video.pause())
}, [url])
```